# GraphQL url is throwing errors

Tags: magento2

I am very new to GraphQl Magento. When I access the graphql url in my installation, following the below tutorial, it throws the below error. 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/graphql/

Do I need to enable any modules, or set any configurations?

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Syntax Error: Unexpected <EOF>",
      "extensions": {
        "category": "graphql"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 4,
          "column": 35
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I've got this error when I was using http request method `GET` instead of `POST`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have this error too when i hit the graphql endpoint in my browser. After a debug attempt, it appears graphql expects a query to be passed. (the function to debug is `\Magento\GraphQl\Controller\GraphQl::dispatch`)

The quick way to get graphql running with examples you find around is to install GraphiQL, then a basic query that works at my end is:

```
  {
        cmsPage(identifier: "no-route") {
        url_key
        title
        content
        content_heading
        page_layout
        meta_title
        meta_description
        meta_keywords
      }
    }
```

For completeness, I have also tested Postman and I have it now working too (with more work than GraphiQL) by setting the following:

Header field **Content-Type** to be **application/json**
Method to be POST

Answer (score 1):

Another possible error might be because your endpoint is getting redirected and dropping the `$_POST` data.

Easy debug, just add to your `index.php` (might be the one in the `/pub` directory):    `var_dump($_POST)` and try your query again.
If the response comes back with an empty string, you know that your issue is that the body of the query is not getting passed to the Magento application.

Make sure the request is a POST and is going the secure_url of the website